VS Code SQL data grid
I am troubled with the data grid of  VS code whenever a query fetches the data in the data grid I need to scroll right even for 2 or 3 columns. Is there any way to fix it? It isn't very pleasant to scroll each time to view data.

Please let me know how to fix it.

I don't use that tool, but: in TOAD, when you right-click the data grid, there's the "Size columns" option which lets you to choose among "Show all / Size to data / Size to headers". Maybe something like that exists in your tool; try to right-click the grid and see what it offers (if anything).

You're on version 24.2.1(latest) ? Default behavior is to resize the columns automatically.

You should be seeing this - the grid, a web component (think html, javascript, css), is resizing the columns for 'best fit' - and this resize will happen automatically as soon as you stop asking for more data to be fetched.
Or in other words, stop scrolling. The more data you ask for (rows, columns), the more time it will take to do the resize.

And for really wide tables, you might like the Single Record Viewer, just right-click in the grid to activate.

